# modem set with class b ip but devices can't ping eachother

Tags: networking, router, vpn, ip, modem

I'm mainly a programmer but I've got quite interested in networking lately and I've started to tinker with my home network a bit.

I was trying to set my spare modem to test changes before rolling them to my actual home network but i got stuck. I've changed the network with base ip `172.27.0.0` and subnet mask `255.255.0.0`.

I have various "servers" and other services like vpn and a domain controller *(i know it's very overkill but I like to play with these things and learn how they work)*. I don't know the correct terminology for some stuff but I would like to have different groups of IPs for different things, i.e. `172.27.1.0` for servers, `172.27.2.0` for devices on the network and `172.27.3.0` for devices connected in vpn.

My understanding is that in theory devices or network set with the subnet mask `255.255.255.0` shouldn't be able to see the other groups' devices, while with the subnet mask `255.255.0.0` *(as it's now set)* I should be able to ping a pc with ip `172.27.2.1` from a pc with ip `172.27.3.1`, right? Well if this is the case then I might be doing something wrong or perhaps the modem I'm trying it with doesn't support communication between different groups of ips and defaults to a subnet mask of `255.255.255.0`?

I hope my situation is clear enough and someone can help me find a solution! Thank you in advance

Comment: That is incorrect.  172.27.0.0 is a subnet of the RFC1918 private range 172.16.0.0/12.  So it is perfectly fine to use in this case.

Comment: I have 2 computers, both with subnet mask `255.255.0.0` and one with the ip `172.27.0.2` and the second one with the ip `172.27.2.1`. my modem has the network set to `172.27.0.1` with subnet mask `255.255.0.0`. when on both PCs I do a ping command to the other pc it just fails...

Comment: After ping fails, does the other device's MAC address at least show up in `ip neigh` or `arp -a`? And can both devices ping the modem (gateway)? What ports does the modem have, physically, and how/where are the devices connected? Were they able to talk before?

Comment: Check that your PC does not have a firewall enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a misunderstanding of the use of subnet masks.

> I don't know the correct terminology for some stuff but I would like to have different groups of IPs for different things, i.e. 172.27.1.0 for servers, 172.27.2.0 for devices on the network and 172.27.3.0 for devices connected in vpn.

The "groups" you refer to are called "subnetworks" or "subnets."  To forward traffic between subnets (*e.g.,* 172.27.1.0/24 to 172.27.2.0/24), you need a router.

> My understanding is that in theory devices or network set with the subnet mask 255.255.255.0 shouldn't be able to see the other groups' devices, while with the subnet mask 255.255.0.0 (as it's now set) I should be able to ping a pc with ip 172.27.2.1 from a pc with ip 172.27.3.1, right?

All devices connected to a subnet must have the same subnet mask.

If you want to restrict access between subnets, you need a router that has access control lists (ACLs).

Comment: This. But also note that if all these subnets are on the same Ethernet/Wi-Fi LAN (more precisely, if they're on the same link-layer multicast/broadcast domain), devices will still be able to see and talk to each other via IETF ZeroConf (a.k.a. Apple Bonjour, mDNS) and other multicast-based discovery protocols. ZeroConf is specifically designed to get around subnet mismatches in order to "just work". So if you really want to separate these devices from talking to each other, you need a VLAN-capable switch so you can put them on separate LANs (separate link-layer multicast/broadcast domains).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply! So do you mean I'm going to need a separate router for each subnet all connected to a main router, which would also be my wlan modem?

Comment: i thought there was a way to set an ip to /16 instead of /24 and they would all automatically see eachother instead of still being their separate subnets of /24 if it makes sense

Comment: No, you need one router with multiple interfaces (a commercial version, not a home router).  You can create one subnet with a shorter mask (/16), but then you have one subnet can't do any filtering between devices.

Comment: I don't need filtering, i would like to assign ips manually for some  static devices, have the dhcp assign in the 172.27.2.x range and my vpn server will assign in the 172.27.3.x range, i just need them to communicate as if they were in the same subnet, nothing more. The problem I'm having is that the devices can't access internet and can't see eachother

Comment: You mentioned *...shouldn't be able to see other groups devices.* The simplest solution is to put them in the same subnet.   If you insist on that numbering scheme, then a /22 or shorter would be fine.  The assignments will be controlled by the DHCP and VPN servers.